# Cura variables and initial G-code commands

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, g-code

Ender 3 Pro, PLA, temps 200 °C and 60 °C.

I want to not heat the nozzle until after Auto Bed Leveling (CR Touch) is complete.  I can do that in the start G-code, but by then, Cura has already heated the nozzle to the temp specified under material and filament starts oozing out during bed leveling.  I'd rather set a variable to that value and call it with `M104` when I'm ready.

This is the start of Cura's g-code:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:2888
;Filament used: 1.96332m
;Layer height: 0.2
;MINX:93.266
;MINY:10.195
;MINZ:0.2
;MAXX:126.734
;MAXY:210.658
;MAXZ:4.2
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 4.13.1
M140 S60
M105
M190 S60
M104 S200
M105
M109 S200
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ; Auto Bed Level (CR Touch)
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
...
```

The lines right after "Generated with Cura_SteamEngine" are the ones I'd like to change but I can't find them in the Cura app.  I know that 60 °C and 200 °C are the temps defined for bed and nozzle.  Cura inserts them as constants for the `M140` and `M104` commands.  I'd like Cura to set variables to those values (like `{bed_temp} = 60`) so I can refer to that variable when I insert the `M140` command in my Custom Start G-code.  Can that be done?

A related question was asked a few years ago and part of the start code example then was:

```
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
M104 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Extruder temperature
M140 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Heat Bed temperature
G28 ; Home all axes
G29 ; BLTOUCH Mesh Generation
M190 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Heat Bed temperature
M109 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Extruder temperature
```

The variable `{material_bed_temperature_layer_0}` was already set but I don't know where or how that was done.

Answer (score 4):

I've sorted this out.  *IF* I include my own heating commands in my start G-Code, Cura knows to NOT add its own heating commands at the start of the G-Code file.

The variables I was referring to have dedicated names.
`material_print_temperature_layer_0` is the printing (extruder/nozzle) temp set under Material in Cura.
`material_bed_temperature_layer_0` is the build plate temp set under Material in Cura.

Cura substitutes the values of those variables for the variable names in the G-code file.

So to avoid filament ooze during auto bed leveling, I set the nozzle temp to 150 °C (hot, but lower than the defined printing temp and low enough to avoid ooze).  I set the bed temp to its defined temp.

Then I auto-level the bed.

Then I heat the nozzle up to its defined printing temp and start the print job.

This is my Start G-code:

```
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
M104 S150 ; Set Extruder temperature for bed leveling
M140 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Heat Bed temperature
M109 S150 ; Wait for Extruder temperature for bed leveling
M190 S{material_bed_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Heat Bed temperature
G29 ; Auto Bed Level (CR Touch)
M104 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Set Extruder temperature
M109 S{material_print_temperature_layer_0} ; Wait for Extruder temperature
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
```

And this is how Cura writes the G-code file:

```
;FLAVOR:Marlin
;TIME:2888
;Filament used: 1.96332m
;Layer height: 0.2
;MINX:93.266
;MINY:10.195
;MINZ:0.2
;MAXX:126.734
;MAXY:210.658
;MAXZ:4.2
;Generated with Cura_SteamEngine 4.13.1
M82 ;absolute extrusion mode
; Ender 3 Custom Start G-code
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G28 ; Home all axes
M104 S150 ; Set Extruder temperature for bed leveling
M140 S60 ; Set Heat Bed temperature
M109 S150 ; Wait for Extruder temperature for bed leveling
M190 S60 ; Wait for Heat Bed temperature
G29 ; Auto Bed Level (CR Touch)
M104 S200 ; Set Extruder temperature
M109 S200 ; Wait for Extruder temperature
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X0.1 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to start position
G1 X0.1 Y200.0 Z0.3 F1500.0 E15 ; Draw the first line
G1 X0.4 Y200.0 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move to side a little
G1 X0.4 Y20 Z0.3 F1500.0 E30 ; Draw the second line
G92 E0 ; Reset Extruder
G1 Z2.0 F3000 ; Move Z Axis up little to prevent scratching of Heat Bed
G1 X5 Y20 Z0.3 F5000.0 ; Move over to prevent blob squish
G92 E0
...
```

I hope this helps someone with a similar question.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `Settings` -> `Printers` menu from the top menu,

[image]

select your active printer (or `Activate` it) and manage your printer trough `Machine Settings`.

[image]

It will open the printer settings,

[image]

there you are able to change the lines you want in the `Start G-code` section.

Note the default Start G-code doesn't include heating up the bed and core, you need to add these after the `G29` in your case. Personally I use heat up bed and continue (`M140`), than heat up core and wait till temperature is reached (`M109`), then heat up and wait until bed temperature is reached (`M190`).